# Movie about a girl taking revenge for the death of her parents

Tags: identify-this-movie, action

I remember pretty well that I have seen a movie like this on television. American, extremely well produced. Should be between 2005 and 2012.

A woman, hot and confident, tries to take revenge on a gang who killed her parents.

I don't remember too much information. The woman knew how to use many types of weapons and seemed supernaturally strong in the movie.

I don't remember that she had anyone fighting with her against the gang.

I think the villain had sharks in his home (put in some aquarium outside).

Somewhere in the movie I remember when the girl got sad about her parents.

**Ending (99% sure):** The director makes you think that the villain escaped in a car, then it turns out the woman had kept her violent dog in his car so that he would rip him up and kill him.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am fairly certain that the movie you're referring to is [Columbiana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colombiana). The actress is Zoe Saldana.

**From wiki:**

> After saying their goodbyes, Fabio and his wife Alicia (Cynthia Addai-Robinson) leave to battle Marco and his men but both of them are gunned down as Cataleya listens from the kitchen. Marco tries to manipulate her into giving the information. When he asks what she wants, she stabs him in the hand with a kitchen knife, saying "To kill Don Luis", and escapes.
>
> Fifteen years later, a 24-year-old Cataleya (Zoe Saldana) has become an accomplished assassin. Her uncle serves as her broker, providing her with contracts. She is assigned to kill the notorious gangster
>   Genarro Rizzo (Affif Ben Badra), who is currently in police custody.
>   Implementing an elaborate plan, she gets herself arrested while
>   dressed in a disguise. She manages to escape from her cell with tools
>   she hid in her disguise, travel through the ventilation system,
>   successfully kill Rizzo, and return to her cell. The next morning she
>   is released.
>
> [Later] Cataleya responds [to Luis] that he is exactly where she wants him to be. Unknowingly, Pepe's two attack dogs are right behind Luis' seat and they violently maul Luis to death.

**Trailer:**

**Shark scene:**

**Ending dog scene:**

Comment: I would appreciate if anyone could edit my answer by including the spoiler tag for the excerpt from Wiki. I can't seem to get it right. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Spoiler tags are not required here and are generally removed if deemed unnecessary. See more info on the [help page](http://movies.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Just finished seeing this great movie. I am also sure this is it. Phenomenal movie.